# How can i use the new UDF functionality to create "Dynamic SQL statement"?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can i use the new UDF functionality to create "Dynamic SQL statement"?
Is there a way to use UDF in order to construct SQL statement based on template and input variables, and later run this query?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions?hl=en says:

> A UDF is similar to the "Map" function in a MapReduce: it takes a
>   single row as input and produces zero or more rows as output. The
>   output can potentially have a different schema than the input.

So your UDF receives just a single row.
Therefore - no, UDF is not for the purpose you described in your question.

You might take a look at views - maybe that will suit you better:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views